# ¿Hay forma de optimizar este ejemplo de condicional if-else?

Tags: php, condiciones, if

Busco hacer una condicional que busque como es esta ó valide pero sin utilizar tantas lineas de codigo

```
if (is_file(PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."/".$controller."Controller.php") || 
    is_file(PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."Controller.php") ) {

    if (is_file(PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."/".$controller."Controller.php") ) {
        require PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."/".$controller."Controller.php";
    }else{
        require PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."Controller.php";      
    }
        $controller .= 'Controller';
        $controller = new $controller();
        $controller->$method($param);
}else{
    echo "La Direccion que trata de Acceder No Existe ";
}
```

Comment: Claro, Lo adecuado en estos casos es el uso de [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) en este enlace hay varios [ejemplos](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto, usando el operador ternario y alguna variable temporal.

```
$esArchivo = is_file(PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."/".$controller."Controller.php");
if ($esArchivo || is_file(PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."Controller.php") ) {
    require PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller.($esArchivo ? "/".$controller : "")."Controller.php";
    $controller .= 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller();
    $controller->$method($param);
} else {
    echo "La Direccion que trata de Acceder No Existe ";
}
```

También puedes hacerlo así:

```
$ruta1 = PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."/".$controller."Controller.php";
$ruta2 = PATH_CONTROLLERS.$controller."Controller.php"; 
if (is_file($ruta1) || is_file($ruta2)) {
    require is_file($ruta1) ? $ruta1 : $ruta2;
    $controller .= 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller();
    $controller->$method($param);
} else {
    echo "La Direccion que trata de Acceder No Existe ";
}
```